# Spring Boot - where to place the jsp files

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, jsp

I am trying to develop a new Spring boot application using MVC as a first step to move my existing Spring MVC application to Spring boot.

However, I am facing an issue with the mapping of jsp files.

> Could not resolve view with name 'hello' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

I have ready many answers in SO, but none seem to solve my issue - I am not planning to use any template engines as I will have a lot of jsps to consider - might be a plan once spring boot is set up.

I have a project structure as below:

```
MyFirstApp
  --src/main/java
    --uk.co.company
      --MainApplication.java
      --ServletInitializer.java
    --uk.co.company.web
      --HelloController.java
  --src/main/resources
    --static
    --templates
    --application.properties
 --src
   --main
     --webapp
       --WEB-INF
         --jsp
           --hello.jsp
  --pom.xml
```

Placing the code below:

**MyFirstAppApplication.java**

```
 @SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
 HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
 @EnableWebMvc
 public class MyFirstAppApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyFirstAppApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

**ServletInitializer.java**

```
  public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder 
application) {
    return application.sources(MyFirstAppApplication.class);
}
}
```

**HelloController.java**

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {  
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String sayHello() {      
    return "hello";
}   
}
```

**hello.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
hellooo
</body>
</html>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>uk.co.company</groupId>
<artifactId>MyFirstApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>MyFirstApp</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp
```

Comment: Standard path for jsp's is `WEB-INF` directory

Comment: can you add jstl dependency `<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  </dependency>`

Comment: Have added the application.properties with the prefix and suffix, still no luck

Comment: No luck with the jstl dependency as well

Comment: are you creating jar or war ?

Comment: Where do you use `ServletInitializer ` ?

Comment: @Zico ServletInitializer is auto generated while creating the Spring Starter Project  on eclipse STS

Comment: @gladiator war file

Comment: You can override SpringApplicationBuilder configure() in your Application class

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 4):

I have created a demo project which is rendering jsp

Git URL : https://github.com/rksharma1401/spring-boot-war

take checkout   then 
mvn package
java -jar target\simple-web-app-tomcat-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
URL : http://localhost:8081/w

Comment: I have updated the pom.xml which pointed me to the problem. I appreciate the solution that it helped me figure out the root cause of this issue. I have posted the solution.

Comment: How did you do this exactly, I downloaded your projects and it works just fine. I created a Web Maven project and created a controller and a main class for the spring boot application, I copied your exact dependencies into the pom, but when I run the project I still don't get the Jsp page that I created, and a web.xml gets created automatically when I run the application, can you post the exact details of how you did it?

Comment: DO you have <packaging>war</packaging>  or jar .... JSP work only in war

Answer (score 3):

I have gone exactly the same path. Upgrading a jsp, xml-based spring application to spring boot 2.
There are few things you need to consider when migrating:

First remove @EnableWebMvc.

Second you need @ComponentScan on top of MyFirstAppApplication class.

Try to read this article, it helped me alot
https://htr3n.github.io/2018/12/jsp-spring-boot/

Third you also need this dependeny together with embed-jasper:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
<version>9.0.22</version>
</dependency>
```

Last but not least this is a shortcut for creating a view handler in java

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp
```

and as far as I know it only works in spring boot 2.
You can have Java implementation instead and debug it to see if it ever hit that.

```
@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");       
    registry.viewResolver(resolver);
}
```

Because in my case for example I didn't even need a specific or default resolver.
I had different resolver for each Controller that I had to define in xml/bean and inject in each class.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was with the version of jar `spring-boot-starter-parent`. For some reason this doesn't work with the version `1.5.3 RELEASE`. It works until version `1.5.2 RELEASE`.

I have updated the `pom.xml`'s parent tag as below:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `@EnableWebMvc` annotation from your Spring Boot class.
By default with `@SpringBootApplication` enables your application as web application. Declaring `@EnableWebMvc` explicitly will disable the auto configuration and Auto setting up DispatcherServlet will be overridden which is causing you the issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is a dependency to include as Spring boot doesn't know how to translate JSP to Servlet.
So,

1. Check the version of your tomcat-embed-core-.jar.
2. Go to that corresponding version release on
   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper
3. Copy the dependency, it will look like-

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.37</version> 
</dependency>
```

here version needs to be updated as per your tomcat-embed-core jar version

4. Update Maven Project so that it can download the jar from repo.

Now you are good to go with your project.

thanKs.

Comment: It is worth to note that while this dependency is needed for JSP compiling it also brings embedded Tomcat and therefore Spring AutoConfiguration overrides other containers (e.g. Jetty). In such case you need to manually provide bean: `JettyServletWebServerFactory`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the directory src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/.. is discouraged if you want to deploy via a jar package.

“Do not use the src/main/webapp folder if your application will be packaged as a jar. Although this folder is a common standard, it will only work with war packaging and it will be silently ignored by most build tools if you generate a jar.”

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-structuring-your-code

Comment: Update 2022: Currently there is no way to package JSP files as standalone JAR and therefore `webapp` directory + WAR packaging is only one correct answer.

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.2/reference/html/web.html#web.servlet.embedded-container.jsp-limitations

Answer (score 1):

Following steps resolved the problem for me.

1. Change the packaging to war in the `pom`:

   `<packaging>war</packaging>`
2. In the `application.properties`, add:

   `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/`

   `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp`

   `spring.main.web-application-type=SERVLET`

(Or alternatively java configuration of view resolver also worked for me)

3. In the `pom`, add these additional dependencies:

   ```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
   ```
4. Run the `war` as uber jar:

   `java -jar warfilename.war`

Answer (score 0):

Why do have two separate java classes(MyFirstAppApplication,ServletInitializer) extending SpringBootServletInitializer class ?

Remove ServletInitializer.java & move configure method from ServletInitializer to MyFirstAppApplication.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing The Same issue and I remove this problem by following changes:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyFirstAppApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyFirstAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}

protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(MyFirstAppApplication.class);
}
```

No need to make `ServletInitializer` new class.